# Parse Json string with Html content

Tags: c#, html, json, json.net

I use Json.net to parse json responce from web, but i have a problem if the json response contain html code.

For example:

```
string hj = @"{""data"": ""<a href=""www.google.com"">Google</a>""}";
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(hj);
```

It raise a exception.

How can I parse the JSon response?

Comment: Actually this is not valid json. That's why you get an error. `href=""www.google.com""` part is breaking it.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON is invalid, so it can't be parsed. You have to escape the quotation marks inside the string:

```
string hj = @"{""data"": ""<a href=\""www.google.com\"">Google</a>""}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode HTML code with System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() method